# Trying to merge two csv files but its showing only the first two lines only

Tags: php, arrays, csv, foreach, import-csv

I am trying to merge two csv files take one field from the first csv and one fields from the second but when I do this its only return me the first/second line of the second file.

```
if ($ext1 == 'csv' && $ext2 == 'csv') {
            $path1 = ROOT . "/uploads/" . md5(uniqid()) . ".csv";
                $path2 = ROOT . "/uploads/" . md5(uniqid()) . ".csv";
                $file1 = $_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'];
                $file2 = $_FILES['upload2']['tmp_name'];

                move_uploaded_file($file1, $path1);
                move_uploaded_file($file2, $path2);

                $file1 = fopen($path1, 'r');
                $file2 = fopen($path2, 'r');

                if (file_exists($path1) && file_exists($path2)) {
                    header('Content-Type: text/csv');
                    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="sample.csv"');

                    $output_name = md5(uniqid()) . ".csv";
                    $output = ROOT . "/uploads/output/" . $output_name;
                    $fp = fopen($output, 'wb');
                    fputcsv($fp, array('campaign', 'spent', 'payout', 'profit', 'roi'), ',');
                    $found_campaigns = [];

                    fgetcsv($file1); // Skip first line
                    while (($data = fgetcsv($file1)) !== FALSE) {
                        array_push($found_campaigns, $data[$campaign]);
                        echo "<pre>";
                        var_dump($found_campaigns); //  Showing the found campgains
                        echo "</pre>";
                        echo "</br>";


                        // Check if the second file have same campgain name with the first file campgain name if yes take the payout field and merge them with the spent field.
// This returning only the data of the two first lines only ( Need to return all the equal fields )
                        $found_in_file_2 = false;
                        $pout = '';
                        while (($data2 = fgetcsv($file2)) !== FALSE && !$found_in_file_2) {
                            var_dump($data2); // Show the fields of the second file if the campgain name are equal to the first file campaign name
                            if ($data2[$campaign2] == $data[$campaign]) {
                                $found_in_file_2 = true;
                                $pout = $data2[$payout];
                            }
                        }

                        $pout = str_replace('$', '', $pout);

                        $line = [
                            $data[$campaign],
                            $data[$spent],
                            $pout,
                            $pout - $data[$spent],
                            ($pout - $data[$spent]) / $data[$spent]
                        ];

                        fputcsv($fp, $line, ',');
                    }

                    $file1 = fopen($path1, 'r');
                    $file2 = fopen($path2, 'r');
                    fgetcsv($file2); // Skip first line
                    while (($data = fgetcsv($file2)) !== FALSE) {
                        if (!in_array($data[$campaign2], $found_campaigns)) {
                            $found_in_file_1 = false;
                            $spt = '';
                            while (($data2 = fgetcsv($file1)) !== FALSE && !$found_in_file_1) {
                                if ($data2[$campaign] == $data[$campaign2]) {
                                    echo $data2[$campaign] . ' ' . $data[$campaign2] . '<br>';
                                    $found_in_file_1 = true;
                                    $spt = $data2[$spent];
                                }
                            }

                            $spt = str_replace('$', '', $spt);
                            $pout = $data[$payout];
                            $pout = str_replace('$', '', $pout);

                            if ($spt > 0) {
                                $roi = ($pout - $spt) / $spt;
                            } else {
                                $roi = 0;
                            }

                            $line = [
                                $data[$campaign2],
                                $spt,
                                $pout,
                                $pout - $spt,
                                $roi
                            ];

                            fputcsv($fp, $line, ',');
                        }
                    }

                    fclose($fp);
                    $now = date("d_m_Y H:i",time());
                    echo '<a class="btn btn-primary" href="uploads/output/' . $output_name . '" download="'. $now .'.csv">Download Merged File</a>';
                }
            }
```

The files content

First file ( Need to get spent field - working ) :

```
Campaign ID Campaign Name   Impressions Rate    Cost
4833222 ZroJumiaNGMob1  15335   0.00014 2.1469
4833236 ZroJumiaNGMob2  36921   0.00015 5.53815
4877020 ZroJumiaNGMob3  781926  0.00015 117.2889
4948833 ZroJumiaNGMob4  900899  0.00026 234.23374
4984715 ZroJumiaNGMob5  440423  0.00021 92.48883
4984722 ZroJumiaNGMob6  542272  0.00024 130.14528
```

Second File ( need to get payout field and put them same row - not working) :

```
Offer.name  name    Stat.impressions    Stat.conversions    Stat.clicks payout
Aliexpress Online Store - revShare International    ZroJumiaNGMob1  0   205 83598   47.4551
Aliexpress Online Store - revShare International    ZroJumiaNGMob2  0   13  12080   1.6562
Aliexpress Online Store - revShare International    ZroJumiaNGMob3  0   50  14750   13.0269
Aliexpress Online Store - revShare International    ZroJumiaNGMob4  0   17  7108    3.5583
Aliexpress Online Store - revShare International    ZroJumiaNGMob5  0   25  11045   2.1942
Aliexpress Online Store - revShare International    ZroJumiaNGMob6  0   70  27187   12.3148
```

Answer (score 0):

You can merge 2 csv file as following

```
$csv1ToArray = parseCsv('FILEPATH');
$csv2ToArray = parseCsv('FILEPATH');
$res = [];
array_walk($csv1ToArray, function($v, $k) use (&$res, $csv2ToArray){
    $res[$k] = array_merge($v,$csv2ToArray[$k]);
});
writeTocsv('merged.csv', $res);
//function to write in csv file
function parseCsv($file){
  if (($handle = fopen($file, "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($line = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $data[] = $line;
    }
  }
 return $data;
}
// function to parse csv in array
function writeTocsv($file, $rows){
  if(!empty($file) && count($rows) > 0 ){
    $fp = fopen($file, 'w');
    foreach ($rows as $fields) {
        fputcsv($fp, $fields);
    }
    fclose($fp);
  }
}
```